# Finding a vectors from determined angle and projection

Tags: solution-verification, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

> Let $a = <3, -4>$. Find all vectors $b=<b_{1},b_{2}>$ such that the angle between a and b is $\arccos(\frac{2}{\sqrt5})$ and $||\mathrm{proj}_{a}b||=2$.

**My Try:**

First of all we know that:
$$\theta = \arccos\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt5}\right)$$

And also from the formula:

$$\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{a \cdot b}{||a|| ||b||}$$

So we have the inequality:

$$\dfrac{a\cdot b}{||a||||b||}=\dfrac{2}{sqrt5}$$

And if we substitute the a and b we get:

$$\dfrac{3b_{1}-4b_{2}}{5\sqrt{b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2}} = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt5}$$

And also from the magnitude of projection we will get:

$$\dfrac{3b_{1}-4b_{2}}{\sqrt{b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2}} = 2$$

But I couldn't go further. Thanks!

Comment: Magnitude of the projection of $b$ onto $a$ is $a\cdot b /|a|$, not $a\cdot b / |b|$.

Comment: Oh yeah sure. I did't see this. Thanks a lot!